# how to solve Datepicker issue on cloning? Update : no helpful answer yet..

Tags: javascript, jquery

Update : no helpful answer yet..

I have a div with multiple elements. On cloning, everything works fine except `datepicker`. On cloning, it creates an input field for date but when I click on it, it refers to the field of which it is cloned from. How can I solve this issue?
I have seen many other posts but can't understand so please answer or not but don't refer any link.

```css
        /* date-time picker*/
        .getCurrentDate {
            background: #e07b53;
            border: 1px solid #666666;
            z-index: 999;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-size: 0.8125rem;
        }

            .getCurrentDate .dp_current {
                background: #E8FFEB !important;
                color: #000 !important;
            }

            .getCurrentDate .dp_hover {
                background: #dc6a3d !important;
                color: #fff !important;
            }

            .getCurrentDate .dp_selected.dp_current {
                color: #333 !important;
            }

                .getCurrentDate .dp_selected.dp_current.dp_hover {
                    color: #fff !important;
                }

                .getCurrentDate .dp_selected.dp_current.active {
                    background: #5a4b4b !important;
                    color: #fff !important;
                }

            .getCurrentDate .dp_daypicker th {
                background: #666;
                color: #fff;
            }

            .getCurrentDate .dp_not_in_month {
                color: transparent !important;
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
            }
        /*----------------------------------------------*/
```

```js
 var toAddCloneCount = 2;
    function AddDestination() {

        var lastCity = document.getElementById("City0").selectedIndex;

        var clone = $("#toAdd1").clone(true);
        clone.find("#City1").attr('id', 'City' + toAddCloneCount);
        clone.find("#days1").prop('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
        clone.find("#toDate1").prop('id', 'toDate1' + toAddCloneCount);
        clone.show();
        clone.attr('id', 'toAdd' + toAddCloneCount++).insertAfter("#toAdd1");
        clone.appendTo("#destinations");

    }
```

```html
<div id="destinations">
                <div id="toAdd1">


                    <table style="width: 100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style8">To </td>
                            <td>
                                
                                <select  id="City1" >
                                </select>

                                    </td>
                            <td>Days to Stay</td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="days1" type="number" min="1"  onkeypress="return false" onkeydown="return false" />
                                
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p>Date: <input id="toDate1" type="text" class="getCurrentDate"   onkeypress="return false" onkeydown="return false" /></p>
                                
                            </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" onclick="AddDestination();" >Add+</button>
                        
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any 'datepicker' field in you example. Do you mean you use jQueryUI Datepicker  ? - then please provide the relevant piece code

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [jQuery.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) with second parameter as true? That will copy all event handlers in addition to DOM element.

```
jQuery.clone(SELECTOR, true);
```

> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children
>   of the cloned element should be copied.